# Python pandas DataFrame copy slice warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with columns like this:

```
PSMTH = PSframe[['Window','Beginning_Of_Date_Range','DOB','End_Of_Date_Range','First_Name','Grade','Last_Name',\
                 'Middle_Init','Reporting_Date','Site_ID','Site_Name','Student_ID','Math_Percentile',\
                 'Math_Scaled_Score','Math_Standard_Error','Math_Test_Date']].dropna(how='all')
```

I am trying to create a new column in a data frame that simply concatenates the contents of 3 other columns like this:

```
PSMTH["WindowSchoolStudent"]=PSMTH["Window"]+PSMTH["Site_Name"]+PSMTH["Student_ID"].map(str)
```

However, I get the following error:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead

I can't figure out how to use `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value` to fix it.

Comment: that looks ok, can you post code the reproduces your warning, also as an aside does this raise a warning: `PSMTH["WindowSchoolStudent"]=PSMTH["Window"]+PSMTH["Site_Name"]+PSMTH["Student_ID"].astype(str)`?

Comment: Sorry, please see edited content above.

Comment: I think because you called `dropna` this returns a copy of the df rows, if you did your line first and then called `dropna` then it wouldn't raise a warning, it depends on what your intentions are here

Comment: I shouldn't say "error" because it's just a warning and my code produces the desired result. I'm just trying to make sure it doesn't bite me later. I'm just trying to create a new, concatenated column and attached it to the original data frame.